# Row norms of a tall matrix with orthonormal columns

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a $n \times k$ matrix with $n > k$.  If the columns of $X$ are orthonormal, then I want to show that the row norms are bounded by 1.  My current solutions involves completing $X$ into an orthogonal matrix and then using the fact that $X^T X  = X X^T = I$.  I would like a more direct argument such as assuming that a row has norm larger than one leads to an immediate contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

This is just the Pythagorean theorem.  Denote the column vectors by $f_1, \dots, f_k$  Let $e_j$ be the usual unit vector with $1$ in the $j$-th position.  Then
$$
e_j = \sum_{l = 1}^k \langle e_j, f_l\rangle \  f_l + u_j,
$$
where $u_j$ is a  vector perpendicular to the span of $f_1, \dots, f_k$.
Hence
$$
1 = ||e_j||^2 =  \sum_{l = 1}^k |\langle e_j, f_l\rangle |^2 + ||u_j||^2.
$$
Hence $\sum_{l = 1}^k |\langle e_j, f_l\rangle |^2 \le 1$.  Note that the $(j, l)$ entry of the matrix is $\langle f_l, e_j \rangle$.

Comment: why do you add $n$ for $e_j$? is $n$ a vector?, if yes could you write its expression? or the $n$ is the number of rows of $X$? I didn't understand the definition of your $n$

Comment: Sorry, poor notation.  I changed it.

Comment: could you please help me in my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103919/confusion-in-the-definition-of-1-norm-of-a-rectangular-matrix

Comment: Is your result true for any norm also?

Answer (score 0):

The squared row norms of a matrix $X$ with orthonormal columns are also known as the leverage scores of $X$. See section 2.4 of [Sketching as a Tool for Numerical Linear Algebra](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4357) for another proof that each of these squared row norms is less than or equal to 1.